# How does newView() for CursorAdapter work?

Tags: android

I'm slightly confused on how the `newView()` of `CursorAdapter` works. I'm interested what `Cursor c` is passed to the method by the Framework in particular. I have a `ListView` which filled with a `CursorAdapter` which contains 4 rows. After some debagging I see two different `Cursor c` objects passed to the `newView()` and this fact confuses me.

I was expecting the different `Cursor` is passed to the method, different `Cursor` object per `row` in the database. So with this assumption in mind I was setting onClick listeners on checkbox element of a listview row, but this just work very strange.

```
  @Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row;
            final Cursor cursor = c;
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            this.defaultDrawable = (Drawable) row.getBackground();
            final CheckBox mStar = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.star);
            mStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mStar.isChecked()) {
                        mDbHelper.updateFavorite(cursor, 1);
                    } else {
                        mDbHelper.updateFavorite(cursor, 0);
                    }
                }
            });

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(row);

            row.setTag(holder);

            return (row);
        }
```

Comment: first Cursors in concept are similar to Iterators ... next you should be aware of ListView optimization ... there is no need to create more than number of visible item of ListView(+ 1-2 more) and Adapter create them with `newView` if Adapter creates enough items starts usig `bindView` on already created views ...

Comment: Yes, I have implemented bindView() for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor is a pointer to where you are at the moment you create the view. In the onClick method, it will be pointing elsewhere in your query.

You can move it to where you want by calling cursor.moveTo();

In the case of a CursorAdapter, a cursor usually has a _ID column, which value is used to identify rows.